# Tkinter multiprocessing and calling functions from another class

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem where I would like to call the `random_task()` function in the ThreadedTask class and wasn't sure how to go about doing this. I am using Python 2.7 if that makes a difference. I would also like to be able to run it inside some sort of loop which would repeat until the application is closed but I will ask that in a different question.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import os, Queue, threading, time

class TestClass(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.create_view()

    def create_view(self):
        self.labelTitle = tk.Label(self, text="page",)
        self.labelTitle.pack()

    def random_task(self):
        print("test")

    def process(self):
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
        ThreadedTask(self.queue).start()
        self.master.after(100, self.process_queue)

    def process_queue(self):
        try:
            msg = self.queue.get(0)
        except Queue.Empty:
            self.master.after(100, self.process_queue)

class ThreadedTask(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        #I want to run random_task() here
        time.sleep(5)
        self.queue.put("Task finished")

app = TestClass()
app.geometry("800x600")
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to extend `ThreadedTask` like so:

```
class ThreadedTask(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, parent, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        self.parent.random_task()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.queue.put("Task finished")
```

And then call it like so (from the `TestClass`):

```
ThreadedTask(self, self.queue).start()
```

However, in the code you gave, `process()` is never called. Doing so will also call `random_task()` from the `ThreadedTask` class.

This, by the way, can be applied to almost every class in Python when needed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ConorYoungs Glad I could help! This 'tweak' is indeed not obvious at first, but worth to keep in mind!